# nohup: failed to run command `.': Permission denied

Tags: shell, alias, source, nohup

I tried execute my script using:

```
nohup . test.sh
```

and

```
nohup . ./test.sh
```

However, I got: `` nohup: failed to run command `.': Permission denied `` each time.

What I'm really trying to do is in my script be able to call commands that I've aliased, but it only works with "`. test.sh`" or "`. ./test.sh`", not "`./test.sh`" or "`sh ./test.sh`" as I get a  "command not found".  But I'd like to be able to run this with "nohup".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`nohup` runs an executable. You need to pass it an external command, i.e. an executable file. You can't call `nohup` on a shell construct such as an alias, function or builtin. `nohup` runs a new process, it doesn't run something inside the existing shell process (since `nohup` itself is a separate process), so `nohup . …` doesn't make sense.

`nohup ./test.sh` is the correct way to run a shell script with nohup. Make sure that the script properly starts with a shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) and that the file is executable (`chmod +x ./test.sh`).